# Error after updating symfony/swiftmailer-bundle to 2.2.5

Tags: symfony, composer-php, swiftmailer

After updating symfony/swiftmailer-bundle to v2.2.5 with composer.phar update I get such error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.2.4)
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.2.5)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files



  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
  The service definition "swiftmailer.mailer" does not exist.                 



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Problem is fixed after downgrading to 2.2.4

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.2.5)
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.2.4)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Installing assets using the hard copy option
Installing assets (part of code removed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use `mailer` service, as it's an alias to the correct swiftmailer service, regardless how it named. For example im v2.3.3 it's `swiftmailer.mailer.default`

But you have to use

```
$container->findDefinition('mailer');
```

> which unlike `getDefinition()` also resolves aliases so if the `$serviceId` argument is an alias you will get the underlying definition.

Comment: I tried to do at the very beginning. But when I call: $container -> getDefinition('mailer'); I get an error: 'InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "mailer" does not exist.'

Comment: Is there a way to get the definition by the alias? When I call $container -> getAlias('mailer') I get object of class \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias with only 2 methods - isPublic, setPublic(boolean). Non 'getAliasedDefition'...

Answer (score 0):

The line that triggerd the error was:

```
$definition = $container->getDefinition('swiftmailer.mailer') ;
```

Error was caused by change of service name. Until 2.2.4 the name was

```
swiftmailer.mailer
```

and since 2.2.5 it is:

```
swiftmailer.mailer.abstract
```

I changed the line to:

```
$definition = $container->hasDefinition('swiftmailer.mailer') ? $container->getDefinition('swiftmailer.mailer') : $container->getDefinition('swiftmailer.mailer.abstract');
```

That fixed the error.

Comment: Why not use the `mailer` definition?

Comment: I tried to do so in the first place, but all I got was: 'InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "mailer" does not exist.'