# Symfony: Unable to replace alias "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real" with actual definition ""

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, symfony

I've encountered a strange error when installing libraries from composer.

After running 'composer install' and installing all libraries this is what I get in the terminal:

Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  Unable to replace alias "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real" with actual definition "".

Strangely on my MAC dev (mac air, homebrew php and mysql) setup I don't have this issue. However on this machine (windows 10, Yoga 900) when installing the the project from my github repo, I've had this issue.

I can't run 'php bin/console debug:container' without the error occuring again.

Versions:
Symfony 3.0.9
SwiftMailer v5.4.3

I've googled the issue and had no luck finding an answer but found related issues:

https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/issues/59

[Error after updating symfony/swiftmailer-bundle to 2.2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182794/error-after-updating-symfony-swiftmailer-bundle-to-2-2-5)

Any help greatly appreciated, unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to solve this one.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, my problem was that I do not set mailer_transport in parameters.yml